# Is it possible to disable embedded H2 jdbc datasource init by .sql script and use entity-annotaed objects instead with no init-data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, h2, spring-test

I work on a spring boot project and I've written some tests against an embedded H2 successfully. In my local environment, my model classes annotated with @Entitiy are used to create my test tables. When I build my project with mvn I get an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script from resource [URL [file:/home/.../.../.../.../.../target/test-classes/data.sql]]; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'script' must not be null or empty
```

As I found [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) this is the expected default behaviour. Thing is that I just need empty tables for my test created by my entitiy models. Like mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate) I thought Spring detects the embedded db automatically and uses "create-drop" for the table lifecycle.

Is there a way to disable this datasource.init process by script oder do I have to add additional propertied in my application.properties file under src/test/resources ? I thougt the default behaves the way I want because when I run it in intellij everything works fine.

**EDIT:**
I made a workaround with creating a data.sql file that has a useless sql statement in it. Now it works but it seems pretty hacky. Still interested if there is a way to remove this auto configure behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate

spring.datasource.continueOnError=true

Spring Boot enables the failfast feature of the Spring JDBC initializer by default, so if the scripts cause exceptions the application will fail to start.

To disable the failfast you can set spring.datasource.continueOnError=true. This can be useful once an application has matured and been deployed a few times, since the scripts can act as “poor man’s migrations” — inserts that fail mean that the data is already there, so there would be no need to prevent the application from running, for instance.